# How to filter a varchar containing android and ios build numbers below a certain version

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have this table that has a user_id and an os_version column. The os version is a varchar column and contains build numbers that look like this

- 4.3
- 10.0.1

I want tried filtering with the following query but it won't work since this filtering logic on strings isn't adequate.

```sql
SELECT
  user_id,
  os_version,
  CASE 
    WHEN os_version < '4.3' THEN TRUE 
    ELSE FALSE 
  END AS min_spec_bool
FROM table
```

This logic flags the 10.0.1 value as `< 4.3` which is not the my intention. My itention is that 10.0.1 should be flagger as False.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the version string into a numeric version.

That can be done by splitting the string on '.' and multiplying each section by powers of 10.

'4.3' could be converted to '430'

Example:

```
WITH mytable (user_id, os_version) AS (
SELECT 1, '4.3'::TEXT
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '10.0.1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '4.2'
)
SELECT
    user_id
  , os_version
  , CASE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 1) WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 1)::INT END * 100
  + CASE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 2) WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 2)::INT END * 10
  + CASE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 3) WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 3)::INT END os_numeric
FROM mytable
WHERE (
    CASE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 1) WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 1)::INT END * 100
  + CASE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 2) WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 2)::INT END * 10
  + CASE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 3) WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE SPLIT_PART(os_version, '.', 3)::INT END
) < 430
```

Also, note that if any of the minor version values exceed 9, then you would have to pick different multipliers.